# Change the useHash option in RouterModule in runtime

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router

I need to load my router module option **useHash** of Angular application with true and sometime with false. its depends on some server state that I'v getting to the window (global) object.

I've tried to load one of 2 components with ngDoBootstrap ([like here this example](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-manually-bootstrap-an-angular-application-9a36ccf86429)), and then load for each component, module with router module. the first one, loads with useHash = true, the second one with false.

this is not working with AOT. can I change the useHash option in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this scenario.

create 2 modules that with different entry component.

add if statement for main.ts

```
if (window.firstModuleToLoad) {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(FirstModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
} else {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(SecondModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```